# Edit from a person who is being quoted as a source, and disapproves somewhat

Tags: discussion, editing, review

I just saw en [edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/58447) in the Suggested Edits queue from a person who <s>claims to be</s> [has proven that she is](https://asplashofmylife.wordpress.com/2015/10/04/travelogue-turkey-istanbul/#comment-3528) the person who was quoted as a source as background information in the [question she was trying to edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/71454/41775). She wanted to say that she believed her material had been somewhat misrepresented.

She apparently tried to comment, but she doesn't have enough rep. She can't answer either, since the question is closed.

What should be done here?

> ******Edited by the blogger from Wordpress who couldn't figure out how to reply to the thread*****: Turkey was as safe as any other city in the world when I went. Taxi drivers everywhere cheat tourists, and men always hit on girls. Nothing out of the blue. The way the statement was added, made the issues we faced, sound much worse. It wasn't that bad! But with respect to the political situation right now, you be your own judge. For any other questions, leave a comment on my blog.

Comment: Question seems to have been deleted, so …

Comment: @Jan Oh, alright. Perhaps it was deleted by OP.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the person should add their own answer if they disagree with the existing one. Editing to explain a misrepresented quote seems weird to me.

Comment: I agree with this, but in this example the question is closed and there are no existing answers. So this user was not in disagreement with any answer, she was in disagreement with the way she had been referred to in the question as a source. And since it was closed there was no way for her to post an answer either.

Comment: Textbook example of spurious closing causing harm: a blogger with direct experience of the matter in hand was prevented from sharing their perspective on their experience with someone who wanted to know about it.